# How to populate Observable with dynamic data loading

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I have a UI component which is populating from data gained from Bus.

```
subscription.add(dataManager.getRadioModels()
            .subscribeOn(dataManager.getScheduler())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<RadioModel>() {
                @Override public void onCompleted() { }

                @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e("There was a problem loading the top stories " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override public void onNext(RadioModel radioModel) {
                    if (radioModel != null){
                        mVersion.setText(radioModel.getPath());
                    }
                }
            }));
```

The problem is that in data manager I create an Observable and when new item is found I need to add this item to Observable. And after that subscription is not working, cause I had subscribed for previous one.

```
@Override
public Observable<RadioModel> getRadioModels() {
    Observable<RadioModel> items = Observable.<RadioModel>empty();

    Observer observer;
    if (observers.containsKey(Radio.class)){
        observer = observers.get(Radio.class);
    }
    else if (isConnected()){
        observer = new Observer(bus, new Class[] { Radio.class });
    }
    else {
        return items;
    }

    Observer.Listener oListener = new Observer.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void objectLost(ProxyBusObject obj) {
            if (obj != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "objectLost: " + obj.getBusName() + " @ " + obj.getObjPath());
                //items.subscribe(item -> item.remove(obj.getObjPath()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void objectDiscovered(ProxyBusObject obj) {
            if (obj != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "objectDiscovered: " + obj.getBusName() + " @ " + obj.getObjPath());
                items.concatWith(Observable.just(new RadioModel()));
            }
        }
    };

    observer.registerListener(oListener);

    return items;
}
```

So basically the problem in objectDiscovered, but I do not know hot to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "subscription is not working"? But one thing to note is that `concatWith` (or most other `Observable` operators) do not change the `Observable` they're called on, but instead return a new object. You would need `items = items.concatWith(Observable.just(new RadioModel()));` to achieve any effect at all. But this still won't do what you want in this case, because when the callback is executed you already returned the previous value of `items`. The easiest way to get this to work is probably a `Subject` or maybe Jake Wharton's https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay.

Comment: Thank you for the respond, I got everything you said. And I am looking for the possible approaches, will take a look at Subject and Jake Wharton's lib. But is there a way may be to hide objects in like Observable<Map<String, RadioModel>>, I just do not get notified that item was added to map or deleted from it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the follow up question, but I'll try: Of course you can have an `Observable<Map<String, RadioModel>>`. Say you were using a `Subject`: `map.put(keyString, radioModel); subject.onNext(map);`

Comment: If I have a Observable<Map<String, RadioModel>>, when I change collection inside of Observable, I do not have subscription triggered.

Comment: `Observable<Map<String, RadioModel>> items = Observable.<Map<String, RadioModel>>empty();
@Override
            public void objectDiscovered(ProxyBusObject obj) {
                if (obj != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "objectDiscovered: " + obj.getBusName() + " @ " + obj.getObjPath());
                    items.subscribe(v -> v.put(obj.getObjPath(), new RadioModel()));
                }
            }`
no subscription triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the Subject approach! It works! Just write your second comment as an unswear i'll mark it as right one.